# Magento 2 - Customer Type Table SQL

Tags: magento2, customer, sql

I need to create a query that will list me as in the admin panel all registred customers, of course, I can do it through the tables customer_entity. However, it does not contain the **customer type** whether it is "Company user" or "Individual user". Where can I find this type of information by default? In which table to look for this in Magento 2?

Answer (score 1):

This is too vague question to advise anything concrete.

Customer model is based on EAV(Entity Attribute Value) and related customer data stored in tables like `customer_entity_*`

EAV metadata for link data is stored in `eav_*` tables

It's present a lot of information in internet which will be helpful. You can search it by keywords like `Magento 2 EAV`

If you have more specific question, please update your Ask

Answer (score 0):

I would like to call a SQL query something to list customers (e-mail addresses and customer type). In most standard tables, this is determined only by a number, but I want the table to appear whether it is "Company user" or "Individual User
[image: "]